# How to access array state or json data on react native?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, react-native

I have state with

```
data: [
  { 'keya': 'Quando analisa','index':0 },
  { 'keyb': 'Modelo de texto','index':1 },
  { 'keyc': 'Parte sofreu alteraes','index':2 },
  { 'keyd': 'Todos os geradores','index':3 },
],
```

Want to access index. Tried

> this.state.data.index

but not getting index value. How to access index?

Comment: Have you tried `this.state.data[index]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `this.state.data` is a array so you either need to loop through the array to get the index value and use it to access all the objects with `index` property like:

```
for(var i=0; i<this.state.data.length; i++){
  console.log(this.state.data[i].index);
}
```

Or you need to explicitly define the index value as `this.state.data[0].index` to get the `index` value of object at index `0` and so on.

Comment: @ShibinRajuMathew glad to help

Comment: use map instead of for loop